# What are the memory implications of passing a MySQLi result to a function in PHP?

Tags: php, optimization, mysqli

Dear gods of Stackoverflow

Let's say I have a MySQL query that selects a large dataset:

```
$query = "SELECT col_1, col_2, ..., col_99 FROM big_table";
```

And I get a MySQLi result like so:

```
$result = $db->query($query);
```

But then instead of dealing with $result in this scope, I pass it to a function:

```
my_function($result);
```

And once inside my_function(), I iterate through each row in the result and do stuff:

```
function my_function($result) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Please help me understand the memory implications of this approach.

In other words, what does $result contain, and are there any pitfalls with passing it to a function? Should I consider passing $result by reference instead? For what it's worth, I won't be needing $result once my_function() is done with it.

Cheers from South Africa!

Comment: $result will be false/true or an object, you don't need to pass it by reference

Comment: `$result` is a resource here. *Not* an Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not have any memory implications at all. `$result` holds a [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php). It does not hold the whole result. It's just a resource Id of the result. MySQL uses this I'd to collect the result.

Answer (score 2):

There are virtually no memory implications to this approach.  PHP passes objects by reference, so very little memory is used when passing an object to a function.

The same is not quite true of arrays, they use a technique called Copy On Write, meaning that if you change an array inside a function then the array will be cloned.

You can always [see for yourself](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) what the impact is.

Answer (score 1):

Objects in PHP 5+ are automatically passed by reference, so passing the result object into a function won't duplicate it.

You can then unset the variable after the function has been called.